# redis client not connecting

Tags: ssh, redis, ssh-keys, node-redis

when i am trying to connect to redis client db using a public key,  by use of following command,

> > ssh -i somekey.pem -v -L 6379 : 127.0.0.1 user@domain.com

when i do so its not connecting and giving the following error

> > OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.4, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
> >         Bad local forwarding specification '6379'

there is no other redis instance running

what is the issue and what should i do to solve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well i solved this

i did not put port number(6379) after host(127.0.0.1)

following command is working now

> > ssh -i somekey.pem -v -L 6379:127.0.0.1:6379 user@domain.com